# Where was Crookshanks in Deathly Hallows?

Tags: harry-potter

We know that Hedwig died, and Pigwidgeon presumably stayed at the Weasleys'. But what about Crookshanks? Is he even mentioned in DH? He seems to just disappear at one point with no explanation.